# Get post by ASC from custome field DATE picker

Tags: plugins, mysql, advanced-custom-fields

i want to custome post by  ASC.  i have some add some post in bachend one of the field date picker. i want to post by date which i set in date picker field

```
<?php
        $args = array(
             'post_type'=>'upcoming_events',
             'order' => 'ASC',

       );
        global $more; 
        query_posts( $args ); 
        while (have_posts()) : the_post(); 
        ?>
```

**Ex.**
some post which i set date(datepicker cusomefiled) and title output is below
**DATE(datepicker)**    **title**

19-12-2013           London 
29-12-2013           Spain
15-01-2014           Paris

**i want to**

**DATE(datepicker)**    **title**

15-01-2014           Paris
19-12-2013           London 
29-12-2013           Spain

Comment: Please look to the side under "Related" for the "date picker" and "order by custom field" questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what you need to do is order it by the custom value of the meta_key date value.

Something like this (untested):

```
$wp_query = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type' => 'upcoming_events',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'meta_query' => array (
        array (
            'key' => 'your_custom_date_key',
            'value' => date('Y-m-d')
            )
        ),
    'orderby' => 'meta_value'
    )
    );
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
$args = array(
                        'post_type' => 'upcoming_events',
        'posts_per_page' => 30,
        'meta_key' => 'date',
        'orderby' => 'meta_value',
        'order' => 'ASC',
            'meta_query' => array(
                array(
                   'key' => 'date',

               )

        ));
```

Comment: Please add an explanation how and why this solves the problem.